# Solr: How to perform a batch request to an external system from a PostFilter?

Tags: solr, lucene, acl

I implemented the security post filtering (using Solr 4.3.1) as proposed here (and it works fine) using a `PostFilter`:
http://searchhub.org/2012/02/22/custom-security-filtering-in-solr/

The comment of the [PostFilter interface](https://builds.apache.org/job/Solr-Artifacts-4.x/javadoc/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/PostFilter.html) says:

> This collector interface also enables better performance when an external system must be consulted, since document ids may be buffered and batched into a single request to the external system.

This is exactly what I want to do.

The plan how to realize this based on the implementation linked above is clear:
Do not call `super.collect(int)` in `collect(int)` of the anonymous class returned by `getFilterCollector(IndexSearcher)`, but memorize the doc IDs and instead. As soon as all docs have been collected (i.e. `collect(int)` has been called on all docs), make the batch request to the external ACL system and call `super.collect(doc)` only for those docs that passed the security check.

But how can I know that a certain call of `DelegatingCollector.collect(int)` was the last one for the current query?
I can’t find any method, neither in `PostFilter`, `DelegatingCollector` nor `ExtendedQuery`, which is called at the end of the collection process.

Can anybody tell me which method I'm missing or how this batch processing can be achieved at all?

Thanks in advance,
Simon

Comment: I don't think you can know that

Comment: I'm afraid that this is true. But how can then `document ids be buffered and batched into a single request to the external system`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friendly support employee at [LucidWorks](http://www.Lucidworks.com) was so kind to point me to the right Solr issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5020

As I used Solr 4.3.1 and Solr 4.5 is not released yet, I couldn't find the solution in the code.