# Batch collecting in Solr PostFilter

Tags: solr, lucene, acl

What I want to do is exactly like this:
[Solr: How to perform a batch request to an external system from a PostFilter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175689/solr-how-to-perform-a-batch-request-to-an-external-system-from-a-postfilter)

and the approach I took is similar:

-don't call super.collect(docId) in the collect method of the PostFilter but store all docIds in an internal map

-call the external system in the finish() then call super.collect(docId) for all the docs that pass the external filtering

The problem I have: docId exceeds maxDoc "(docID must be >= 0 and < maxDoc=100000 (got docID=123456)"

I suspect I am storing local docIds and when Reader is changed, docBase is also changed so the global docId, which I believe is constructed in super.collect(docId) using the parameter docId and docBase, becomes incorrect. I've tried storing super.delegate.getLeafCollector(context) along with docId and call super.delegate.getLeafCollector(context).collect() instead of super.collect() but this doesn't work either (got a null pointer exception)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code for the CollapsingQParserPlugin in the Solr codebase, particularly [CollapsingScoreCollector.finish](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-core/4.9.0/org/apache/solr/search/CollapsingQParserPlugin.java#CollapsingQParserPlugin.CollapsingFieldValueCollector.finish%28%29).

The docId's you receive in the collect call are not globally unique.  The Collapsing collector makes them unique by adding the docBase from the context to the local docId to create a globalDoc during the collect() phase.

Then in the finish() phase, you must find the context containing the doc in question and set the reader/leafDelegate depending on what version of Solr your running.  Specifying the right docId with the wrong context will throw Exceptions.  For the Collapsing collector, you iterate through the contexts until you find the first docBase smaller than the globalDoc.

Finally, if you added docBase in collect(), don't forget to subtract docBase in finish() when you call collect() on the appropriate DelegationCollector object, as the author may or may not have done the first time.